# grep with regex

Tags: regex

I have two quick question with regex with grep.

1. what does `\?` mean? I didn't find the explanation for question mark (`?`)
2. How can I achieve `or`? for example, the phone number xxx-xxx-xxxx but the first part could be (xxx)

For example, there might be a digit or not between two letters, such as `a1b` and `ab`, how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` has special meaning in a regular expression. If you want to match a literal question mark, you need to escape it - `\?`

If you want to match a string both with an without a particular part, you use the question mark - `/^a1?b$/` will match either `ab` or `a1b`.

Comment: In grep it's the other way 'round: `?` matches a question mark and `\?` is the zero-or-one quantifier.  Unless you use the `-E` option, that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep ".*a1\?b.*" files
```

Comment: In gnu grep, the `*` character does not need a backslash to function as a quantifier, but `?` does.  However, the `.*` at either end is redundant, since grep always returns the whole line in which the match was found.